# Is it possible/logical to launch a data science app that needs to access structured and unstructured data, into an AWS container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-redshift, amazon-ecs

My company has a few ML data science applications that we are looking to launch.
When I look on AWS's website, the only options I see for storage are EFS and EBS, is it possible to have your container application connect to an AWS database solution such as redshift or MongoDB?

If so, how would you generally go about doing that?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39417515/8857601) or [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-task-database-connection/) answer your question?

Comment: Also see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-task-connect-rds-database/)